# VBA command button to return next value in list after matching a reference value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a command button that will be used to return the next result in a list after the current value.

Below is my current code

```
Range("A2").Value = [HLOOKUP(A2,'Item Database'!A2:A100000,2,FALSE)]
```

The function should check the value of A2, find it on "Item Database' and change the value in A2 to the new value from the reference list.

The current code works for two clicks then always returns #N/A

I'm not sure why, any thoughts as to how I can do this more effectively or how to fix this line of code so that it doesnt error out after 2 uses?

Comment: How would I get it to return the value 1 cell below instead of 1 column over using Vlookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim f As Range, c as range

Set c = Activesheet.Range("A2")
Set f = Sheets("Item Database").Range("A2:A100000").Find( _
                c.Value,lookin:=xlvalues, lookat:=xlwhole )

if not f is nothing then c.value = f.offset(1, 0).value
```